# background image

Tags: html, css

I have this html line

`<body style ="background-color : pink;background-image : url('.\img\summer.jpg') ;" >`

it works on IE8 but not firefox ,opera, google chrome or apple safari (only color shows)

I read many post with about this and tried all the solution still not working

on the other hand , if I stick to IE8

`<table  style="position:fixed;
                    left:25px;
                    top:250px;" border=1>`
doesn't work ,  though it works on all the other browsers , see my problem .. I need to use bg image and fixed position together

any ideas ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `\` with `/`.

Forward slashes are the standard directory separator in HTML pages, and servers won't recognize backslashes. I guess IE converts them into forward slashes automatically.

Comment: oh God !! who knew that little / can make such a mess ^^
thanks guys u r the BEST

Comment: Makes sense.  Backslashes are a microsoft thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
<body style="background:pink url(img/summer.jpg);">
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your background image, first use forward slashes in the URL that you are using, e.g. `./img/summer.jpg`.

Second, remember that the URL of the image is relative to the file where the CSS is located (in this case, the HTML file).

Answer (score 0):

the IE 6 and below doesn't know `position:fixed`, but there are a lot of workaround (als google fore "IE position fixed") - [this](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/) is just one of them i used some time ago.

to the background-image: i think the main problem here is using backslashes ( \ ) instead of "normal" slashes ( / ) - change that and i will work in other browsers, too.

Comment: IE < 7 doesn't know `position: fixed`, but the newer ones do.

Comment: thank for the hint Pekka, i overlooked the "8" after "IE" in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body background ="someimg.jpg" bgcolor="#33333" >
```

this should work. i have tested in chrome and it is working fine for me.

hope this helps

Comment: This is not wrong as such, but old, deprecated syntax. CSS is really the way to go in 2011